# Find match of exactly the same string in R column that has both numeric and character items

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a column that has numeric and strings. I'd like to find only those rows that has a particular string and not the others. In this case, I only need rows that has SE and not the others.

```
df :  
names
SE123, FE43, SA67
SE167, SE24, SE56, SE34
SE23
FE36, KE90, LS87
DG20, SE34, LP47
SE57, SE39
```

Result df

```
names
SE167, SE24, SE56, SE34
SE23
SE57, SE39
```

My code

```
df[grep("^SE", as.character(df$names)),]
```

But this selects every row that has SE. Would somebody please help in achieving the result df? Thanks.

Comment: Hi shreya, can you add the output of `dput(df)` to youe post?

Comment: What is your filtering logic?

Comment: Why don't you want the first line in your output ? Don't you want to extract rows whose name starts with "SE" ?

Comment: Thanks @fmarm. no wait. I only want rows that contains SE. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Which particular string are you trying to find? If it is `SE`, then what is the problem with "selecting every row that has SE"?

Comment: Also note that a column can have only one type; if some of its values are strings, then they all are strings, even if some of the strings are "123" or otherwise look like numerals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your expected output it looks like you want to select those rows where every element starts with `"SE"` where each element is a word between two commas.

Using base R, one method would be to split the strings on `","` and select rows where every element `startsWith` `"SE"`

```
df[sapply(strsplit(df$names, ","), function(x) 
          all(startsWith(trimws(x), "SE"))), , drop = FALSE]

#                    names
#2 SE167, SE24, SE56, SE34
#3                    SE23
#6              SE57, SE39
```

If you want to find presence of `"SE"` irrespective of position maybe `grepl` is a better choice.

```
df[sapply(strsplit(df$names, ","), function(x) 
             all(grepl("SE", trimws(x)))), , drop = FALSE]
```

Make sure you have `names` as character column before doing `strsplit` or run

```
df$names <- as.character(df$names)
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. In my original dataset, some rows are also like 123SE. Is there a way to find those rows that contain only SE irrespective of its position in the string?

Comment: @ShreyaAgarwal Yes, updated the post with `grepl` that should work irrespective of the position.

Answer (score 1):

```
names[!grepl("[A-Z]",gsub("SE","",names))]
[1] "SE167, SE24, SE56, SE34" "SE23"                    "SE57, SE39"
```

You can remove the `SE` from all strings and then look for any character. Strings having only `SE` will not contain any other character and are thus kept by the filter.
(This also works if you have `25SE`)